# Converting numbers to float with 2 decimal places

Tags: java, decimal

```
float f = 0.00f;
System.out.println(f);
```

gives the output:

```
0.00
```

I'd like to format a number represented by a percentage to 2 decimal places. But the result ***should be a float*** and **not** a string.

e.g.

```
10.001 needs to be converted to 10.00
0.0 needs to be converted to 0.00
78.8  needs to be converted to 78.80
```

The values thus formatted will be assigned to a float.. how would one accomplish this?

Comment: You're asking for something that does not make sense. A float is a float. It is represented by 32 bits of data. A string is a string.

Comment: In Java, the float `0.000` is exactly the same as the float `0.0` . There's no way to distinguish them.

Comment: As every other programmer, you must understand the nature of the floating-point number. It is **not a decimal number**.

Comment: The closest you can get is to _round_ the value to a multiple of `0.01` (and still only get the closest representable value).

Comment: What you request is a bad idea.  Try using an int to store hundredths, then display "" + (i/100) + "." + (i%100).  The literal answer is ((float)Math.round(float*100))/100.0 but please figure out why not to do that.

Comment: Thanks to all that replied. I'm just frustrated because I'm using this 3rd party api to generate an xml and one of the properties that is required to be represented as a percentage has a return type of  float... I'll need to figure out how to manipulate this api!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, you can't do that. There's no guarantee that a particular decimal value can be represented by a float that has only two digits right of the decimal.

A float is the wrong data type for this kind of precision. You need to use a decimal type or a scaled integer instead.

Assignment works the same way. If you assign the value 133.47 to a floating-point variable, your environment will assign the *closest valid floating-point number* to the variable. The closest valid floating-point number will *probably* not be 133.47.

You can compile and execute this program in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  float r;
  r = 133.47;
  printf("%.2f, %f\n", r, r);
  return 0;
}
```

It prints these values on my system

```
$ ./a.out
133.47, 133.470001
```

Formatting to two decimal places changed the way 'r' looks, but it didn't change its value. Your system will do floating-point arithmetic based on the actual value, not the formatted value. (Unless you also change the data type.)

Comment: +1.  A float has precision in binary, not decimal; there's no such thing as rounding a float to 0.01.

Answer (score 7):

```
private float parse(float val){       
     DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
     return Float.valueOf(twoDForm.format(val));
}
```

As long as you call it passing an valid float, your result will be a float.
But you can't show the right most zero if its not a String.

Comment: That's just a creative way to round the number. I still like it.

Comment: There is a chance this gives you something like "412652.5499999999999998' right?

Comment: tried this.. but it doesn't work for all cases. e.g. 0.0 will not give you 0.00

Answer (score 0):

Floats don't have decimal places. They have binary places. It follows that the only fractions that can be represented exactly in a float to two decimal places are 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75. In all the other cases what you are asking is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Padding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float value = 10.001f;
        DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        String formattedValue = decimal.format(value);
        System.out.println(formattedValue);
    }

}
```

Output : 10.00